# Python: Named placeholders How to organize data in a string array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, firebase

I am using Firebase Database. I am reading a child and receiving this data:

Input:

```
Connection = db.child(UniqueID).child("Devices").get()
Data =Connection.val()
print(Data)
print(Data[0])
print(Data[1])
```

Output:

```
[None,{'DeviceAddress': '1', 'DeviceType': 'Heat', 'Status': 'Heat Alarm'},
{'DeviceAddress': '2', 'DeviceType': 'Smoke', 'Status': 'Smoke Alarm'},
{'DeviceAddress': '3', 'DeviceType': 'Button', 'Status': 'Button Alarm'}]

None

{'DeviceAddress': '1', 'DeviceType': 'Heat', 'Status': 'Heat Alarm'}
```

How can I sort the data like this:

sortedData=Data[1] "some codes here"

sortedData[0] -> contains '1'

sortedData[1] -> contains 'Heat'

or

sortedData[DeviceAddress] -> contains '1'

sortedData[DeviceType] -> cointains 'Heat'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a DataFrame from the library pandas you will be able to access data categorically and by index.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

Data = [None,{'DeviceAddress': '1', 'DeviceType': 'Heat', 'Status': 'Heat Alarm'},
{'DeviceAddress': '2', 'DeviceType': 'Smoke', 'Status': 'Smoke Alarm'},
{'DeviceAddress': '3', 'DeviceType': 'Button', 'Status': 'Button Alarm'}]

data_frame = DataFrame(Data[1:])

sortedData = data_frame.iloc[0]   # this gets first row of data

print(sortedData.iloc[0])         # get the value by index
print(sortedData.DeviceType)      # get the value by category
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the dictionary values inside a loop to get each list.

```
Data = [None,{'DeviceAddress': '1', 'DeviceType': 'Heat', 'Status': 'Heat Alarm'},
{'DeviceAddress': '2', 'DeviceType': 'Smoke', 'Status': 'Smoke Alarm'},
{'DeviceAddress': '3', 'DeviceType': 'Button', 'Status': 'Button Alarm'}]

tempdata = Data[1:]
for e in tempdata:
  vals = list(e.values())
  print(vals)
```

output

```
['1', 'Heat', 'Heat Alarm']
['2', 'Smoke', 'Smoke Alarm']
['3', 'Button', 'Button Alarm']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I read vals[0],  can I get '1' ?